# concatenate first name middle name and last name if found in the same table

Tags: sql-server, parsing, concatenation

There are around 60 tables which has first name, middle name and last name columns.

Some tables have different column names (Eg: Fname, Mname, Surname etc.) and some does not have middle name and some have full name. There are several such combinations

I need to identify if the first name, middle name and last name or these 3 columns exists or if it exists with different naming conventions in the same table. If they do, then concatenate all 3 columns and display the concatenated results, otherwise display the name or full name as is

I tried SQL based on `information.schema.columns` but I am not getting there. Any help is appreciated

```
FirstName   MiddleName  LastName    Name
kevin        c           nash       Kevin c nash
robert  d   Sy                      robert d sy
            
            
fname   mname   lname   
roberto   a     carlos  
micheal   d     fret    
            
            
fname       lname   Full Name
roberto     carlos  roberto carlos
micheal     fret    micheal fret
```

This is the SQL that I have tried so far:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%first%'
```

Comment: Why do you have 60 tables all with first, middle and last name columns? This smells like a design flaw to me,

Comment: As for the question, sample data, expected results, **and** *your* attempts will help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Larnu, we have source data coming from disparate sources and they have first name, last name and middle name values

The data is from 60 different excel files which I have loaded as tables in sql server database

Sample Data

Table 1
first name  middle name      last name
Jean             d                         Agnes

fname        mname      lname     full name
Ryan              lansing       tela    Ryan lansing tela

Such combinations exist in 60 different tables with 60 different column names

Comment: [Edit] your question, and put the sample data, expected results and (again) *your* attempts in there.

Comment: just edited my question

Comment: Images of text don't help us help you... Text is text... Post is as text. You also forgot to include your attempt(s)

Comment: I posted it as text but does not align properly after I post it. tried to make an attempt using information.schema.columns but I am unable to get an idea

SELECT
TABLE_SCHEMA,
TABLE_NAME,
COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%first%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, lets match on multiple criteria, I would suggest that `%first%` is not enough, it won't match `FName` for instance, so lets include `%name%` in the search:

> In fact, based on your example data, `%name%` should be enough!

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%first%' OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%name%'
```

If you are happy that all the tables are represented in this list, then we can move on to the next step...

We can discover the optimal column names by applying some simple `CASE` logic and  grouping by the table name:

> This effectively a manual `PIVOT` over the previous resultset

```
;WITH TableSchema as 
(
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME as [Name], COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
    IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME as [Name]
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%first%' OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%name%'
        )
)
SELECT t.[Name]
, MIN(FName) as [FName]
, MIN(MName) as [MName]
, MIN(LName) as [LName]
FROM TableSchema t
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT
    CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('fname','firstname','first','name_first') THEN COLUMN_NAME END as [FName]
    ,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('mname','middleName','name_middle') THEN COLUMN_NAME END as [MName]
    ,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('lname','lastname','name_last') THEN COLUMN_NAME END as [LName]
) as NameColumns
GROUP BY t.[Name]
HAVING COUNT(FName) > 0
```

*I've added some additional cases so my database names came up*

| Name | FName | MName | LName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dbo.Person | Name_First | Name_Middle | Name_Last |
| dbo.ResidencyApplication | FName |  | LName |

Now from there, you either use a cursor, or other code techniques to execute statements using those table and field names.

This can be done as a one shot by generating a script from the result of the above query and using `SP_EXECUTESQL` and capturing the results into a table variable so you can continue to process them:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @ValueTable TABLE
(
    TableName VARCHAR (100),
    FName VARCHAR(100),
    MName Varchar(100),
    LNAME VARCHAR(100)
);

DECLARE @curTableName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @curFName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @curMName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @curLName VARCHAR(100);

DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FOR 

WITH TableSchema as 
(
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME as [Name], COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
    IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME as [Name]
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%first%' OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%name%'
        )
)
SELECT t.[Name]
, MIN(FName) as [FName]
, MIN(MName) as [MName]
, MIN(LName) as [LName]
FROM TableSchema t
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT
    CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('fname','firstname','first','name_first') THEN COLUMN_NAME END as [FName]
    ,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('mname','middleName','name_middle') THEN COLUMN_NAME END as [MName]
    ,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('lname','lastname','name_last') THEN COLUMN_NAME END as [LName]
) as NameColumns
GROUP BY t.[Name]
HAVING COUNT(FName) > 0

OPEN tableCursor

FETCH next FROM tableCursor INTO @curTableName, @curFName, @curMName, @curLName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @curTableName + ''',' + QuoteName(@curFName) + ',' + IsNull(QuoteName(@curMName),'NULL') + ',' + QuoteName(@curLName) + ' FROM ' + @curTableName;

    INSERT INTO @ValueTable
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql 

    FETCH next FROM tableCursor INTO @curTableName, @curFName, @curMName, @curLName
END;

CLOSE tableCursor;
DEALLOCATE tableCursor;

SELECT *, FName + ISNULL(' ' + MName,'') + ISNULL(' ' + LName,'') as FullName
FROM @ValueTable
```

From my test database, the following is a sub-set of the results:

*These names are all fictious, any resemblance to persons actual or historic is purely coincidental, and due to a lack of creativity on my part*

| TableName | FName | MName | LNAME | FullName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dbo.Person | Admina | NULL | Davis | Admina Davis |
| dbo.ResidencyApplication | William | Pat | Partridge | William Pat Partridge |
| dbo.Person | Robert | NULL | Adams | Robert Adams |
| dbo.Person | Clarice | NULL | Carell | Clarice Carell |
| dbo.Person | Phillis | NULL | Hoffman | Phillis Hoffman |
| dbo.Person | Frederick | NULL | Fakkman | Frederick Fakkman |
| dbo.Resident | Regina | NULL | Nurse | Regina Nurse |
| dbo.Person | Emily | NULL | Nursette | Emily Nursette |
| dbo.Person | Peter | Cyril | Assisi | Peter Cyril Assisi |
| dbo.Person | Mavis |  | Moppit | Mavis Moppit |
| dbo.Person | Maurice | NULL | Maintman | Maurice Maintman |
| dbo.Person | Timothy | NULL | Kitchener | Timothy Kitchener |
| dbo.ResidencyApplication | Bruce | NULL | Washington | Bruce Washington |
| dbo.ResidencyApplication | Linda | NULL | Lifette | Linda Lifette |
| dbo.ResidencyApplication | Trevor | NULL | Tekker | Trevor Tekker |

Comment: Thank you so much Chris Schaller for taking time. I will try this for sure

Comment: The initial query is not picking up names like Employee's First Name, Employees Middle Name, Employee's Last Name. Does this needs to be added any where in the query?

Comment: I added below in the cross apply


CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('fname','firstname','first','name_first','Employee First Name','First Name') THEN COLUMN_NAME END as [FName]
    ,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('mname','middleName','name_middle','Employee Middle Name','Middle Name') THEN COLUMN_NAME END as [MName]
    ,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('lname','lastname','name_last','Employee Last Name','Last Name') THEN COLUMN_NAME END as [LName]

I get this error after I do that

Comment: I am getting this error after adding above

Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'First'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Middle'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Last'.

(2639 rows affected)
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Name'.

Comment: Worked Chris Schaller. Thanks a ton. I had to add square brackets to so that the column names that has spaces gets detected properly

Comment: @msv, that makes sense, in a solution like this we already accept we don't know what the field names are so it's best to _always_ escape fields, there is even a function in SQL server to do that for you `QuoteName`